# How to use interactive session to access variables in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just learned that you can do python -i something.py in order to run the script and then start an interactive session. But if I do dir(), I don't have access to anything inside main() or any other function. Is there a way to gain access? Because otherwise this might not be very useful.

Comment: To do that, call [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint).

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "gain access"? Once a block is exited, it has no internal state (bar closures). Thus, once the script ends and the interactive session begins, there's nothing to look at. if you mean to inspect during computation, take a look at breakpoints like wim's suggested.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!!